# Prestashop Order - Blank Shipping Page

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a local installation of Prestashop 1.6, one I wish to extend somewhat.

I am going through the usual five-step order checkout process, and at "Shipping", I get a blank page.

***How do I fix this?***

I have checked online and done the following changes to my local prestashop installation

1. My PHP memory limit is now 128M
2. I have deleted all override files
3. `_PS_MODE_DEV_` is currently set to `true`
4. I have cleared all Smarty caches

Some more detail...

I checked the Network tab of my Web Inspector and the request returns a 200; but the response is blank.

Comment: enable error reporting and check what error is there?

Comment: There's no error on the server side since it returns a 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with in `C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\translations\en\errors.php` on line 419. There was a syntax error here.

Why this is shocking is because this was straight after the installation of Prestashop. What may have caused this problem is because I put Prestashop on source control (Git) to track my extending it.

Also, this error translation was triggered because there was no shipping carrier configured on my local Prestashop.